# For any real number $x$, if $ x^3+2x+33\neq 0$, then $x+3 \neq0$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

How to solve this type of sum using indirect proof. Appreciate if anyone can explain it step by step.

Comment: What about contrapositive?

Comment: yes contrapositive is ok. but i don't know how to apply it to solve this.

Answer (score 5):

Proving by contrapositive: Let $P$ be the statement $x^3 + 2x + 33 \neq 0$, $Q$ be $x + 3 \neq 0$. We wish to show that $\neg Q \implies \neg P$.

If $\neg Q$, then $x + 3 = 0$ and $x = -3$. Hence $x^3 + 2x + 33 = (-3)^3 + 2(-3) + 33 = 0$, and we establish $\neg P$.

Comment: Henry, can you please explain it further?

Comment: @Rohit Essentially we are trying to show that $x + 3 = 0$ implies  $x^3 + 2x + 33 = 0$, which would establish the contrapositive $x^3 + 2x + 33 \neq 0 \implies x + 3 \neq 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Your statement is true. But we can even establish that the converse is true.

Note that $$x^3+2x+33=(x+3)(x^2-3x+11)$$
But, since the polynomial discriminant is negative, for any real number, $x^2-3x+11 \neq 0$.

So we have that if $x^3+2x+33=0 \Rightarrow x+3=0$.

Also, since $(-3)^3+2(-3)+33=0$, we have that $x+3=0 \Rightarrow x^3+2x+33$.

Thus, we have that $x^3+2x+33=0 \Leftrightarrow x+3=0$.

This implies that $$x^3+2x+33 \neq 0 \Leftrightarrow x+3 \neq 0$$